Pdfkit table on multiple pages don't respect headerspace
I'm adding tables using the pdfkit-table. At the end of my code i add a Header to all my pages. The header space has been set beforehand.
So to add the tablepages i also pass along the Y coördinate taking in mind my general header that will be added.
                    let tableOptions = {
                        y: doc.page.margins.top + headerHeight + 5
                    };
                
                    (doc as PDFDocumentWithTables).table(table, tableOptions);

                    doc.on('pageAdded', () => {

                        console.log("TESTING PAGEADDED " + doc.y + " ||| Widget:" + widget.widgetType);
                        //trying to figure out if i can do something here.
                    });

The problem i'm having is that on the first page the Y coördinate is correctly used, and the table starts below my header, but since the table is large, there are multiple pages added to finish the table, and on these the Y coördinate starts at the top, the options aren't used. So the header ends up on top of the first couple of lines of those pages.
Note i also have svg's etcetera in this report. Not sure if people need to know.
Note my reputation is too low, maybe someone else should consider adding a 'pdfkit-table' tag
